# how to fix "the server responded with a status of 404 ()" for all static resources after using Nginx

Tags: spring-boot, web, nginx

All static resources return `GET http://www.gogogo.com:8888/js/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`
and then cannot go to the main page without port number.

I uploaded the spring-boot jar file to Google Cloud server (centos7)
and followed the instruction to set all environment include Nginx. The website is available to open use www.gogogo.com:8888 or port number 8080 but no CSS/JS.

I think the problem is the server didn't go to the correct place to find static resources and after a lot of search on google. I still can't fix the problem. The web on my local page works well and the direction is shown on chrome like "localhost:8888/js". All the static resources are under the webapp file.

This is how I link JS in HTML: `<script src="js/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

The address in the project is `gogogo/src/main/webapp/js`.

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
server {
    listen       8080 default_server;
    listen       [::]:8080 default_server;
    server_name  www.gogogo.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location ~ .*\.(js|css|img|jpg|svg|gif|png|bmp|swf|ttf|woff|svg|map|eot)$ {
    root /gogogo/;
    }
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Another problem is I cannot connect to the website using www.gogogo.com directly.

//////////////////error log///////////////////////////////
"Same Url as before" == www.gogogo.com
2019/02/10 14:23:46 [error] 23153#0: *26 open() "/gogogo/css/nav.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), cl
ient: 31.205.233.115, server: www.gogogo.com, request: "GET /css/nav.css HTTP/1.1", host: "www.gogogo.com:8080", referrer: "http://"www.gogogo.com:8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:23:46 [error] 23153#0: *27 open() "/gogogo/js/moment/2.22.2/moment.js" failed (2: No such file or
 directory), client: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /js/moment/2.22.2/moment.js HTTP/1.1
", host: ""Same Url as before":8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:23:46 [error] 23153#0: *17 open() "/gogogo/css/home.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), c
lient: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /css/home.css HTTP/1.1", host: ""Same Url as before"
:8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:23:46 [error] 23153#0: *20 open() "/gogogo/img/utility/white.png" failed (2: No such file or dire
ctory), client: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /img/utility/white.png HTTP/1.1", host: "
"Same Url as before":8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:23:53 [notice] 23259#0: signal process started
2019/02/10 14:24:06 [error] 23264#0: *2 open() "/gogogo/js/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" failed (2: No such file
or directory), client: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /js/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js HTT
P/1.1", host: ""Same Url as before":8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:24:06 [error] 23264#0: *3 open() "/gogogo/js/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js" failed (2: No such file or di
rectory), client: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /js/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js HTTP/1.1", ho
st: ""Same Url as before":8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:24:06 [error] 23264#0: *4 open() "/gogogo/js/axios/0.17.1/axios.min.js" failed (2: No such file o
r directory), client: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /js/axios/0.17.1/axios.min.js HTTP/
1.1", host: ""Same Url as before":8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:24:06 [error] 23264#0: *9 open() "/gogogo/js/moment/2.22.2/moment.js" failed (2: No such file or
directory), client: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /js/moment/2.22.2/moment.js HTTP/1.1"
, host: ""Same Url as before":8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:24:06 [error] 23264#0: *10 open() "/gogogo/css/nav.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), cl
ient: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /css/nav.css HTTP/1.1", host: ""Same Url as before":8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:24:07 [error] 23264#0: *4 open() "/gogogo/css/footer.css" failed (2: No such file or directory),
client: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /css/footer.css HTTP/1.1", host: "www.gogogo.
com:8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:24:07 [error] 23264#0: *3 open() "/gogogo/img/utility/white.png" failed (2: No such file or direc
tory), client: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /img/utility/white.png HTTP/1.1", host: "w
ww.gogogo.com:8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:24:07 [error] 23264#0: *2 open() "/gogogo/css/home.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), cl
ient: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /css/home.css HTTP/1.1", host: ""Same Url as before":
8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"
2019/02/10 14:24:07 [error] 23264#0: *1 open() "/gogogo/img/utility/white.png" failed (2: No such file or direc
tory), client: 31.205.233.115, server: "Same Url as before", request: "GET /img/utility/white.png HTTP/1.1", host: "w
ww.gogogo.com:8080", referrer: "http://"Same Url as before":8080/home"

Comment: Does the DNS get resolved properly ? Where it is hosted ?

Comment: @Barath I use godaddy to resolve dns, and since it can use www.gogogo.com to see the web, I think it's properly(by the way, I only use External ip on ''A' type without port number, is this correct?).

Comment: Pls share nginx logs, I hope both app 8888 and nginx are running in same instance (ip which you mentioned as part of DNS record ) . Any load balancer in place ? How about security/firewall rules?

Comment: @Barath Thank you for replying.I changed the firewall setting in gcd and both 8080 and 8888 is available.and what does load balancer mean?(the error log is pushed)

Comment: @Barath I tried use jar to run locally and found same error, the problem is direction inside jar is different to the package, sorry to be silly